# display data from two different fields

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a friend system on a website of mine and I am very well accomplished in PHP/MYSQL but I am just stumped at this one. I am trying to create a list of a certain user's friends. The MYSQL table 'friend' works with two fields RelatingUser and RelatedUser and when a friend request is sent to RelatedUser, they create a row with both user's names on it.

But basically I am running a basic query with intentions of grabbing specific results from both fields and then displaying them by id. Usually I would use mysql_fetch_assoc and then echo the variable but there are two different variables and i want them in order of their id.

Any ideas?

```
      $users = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['username']);

      $other_friend_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friend WHERE RelatingUser='$users' || RelatedUser='$users'");

       while( $other_friend_assoc = mysql_fetch_assoc($other_friend_query) ) {
$friend_related = $other_friend_assoc['RelatedUser'];
$friend_relating = $other_friend_assoc['RelatingUser'];  

      }
```

Comment: Don't use the mysql* functions - they are not secure. Use PDO or mysqli*

Comment: Do you mean that the resultset should ordered either by "RelatedUser" or "RelatingUser"?

Comment: It should be ordered by the id for the rows which contain the users name in either Related or Relating @Ifthikhan

Comment: @NoahSmith wouldn't a simple "order by id asc" suffice the requirement?

Comment: what would i echo though, thats the real problem @Ifthikhan

Answer (score 1):

If the records are to be ordered by an id other than the ones in RelatedUser/RelatingUser,
and the only problem is to echo the right field, this should do:

```
echo $friend_related == $users ? $friend_relating : $friend_related;
```

Otherwise, if you want the records ordered by either RelatedUser or RelatingUser, depending on which one is not known, a query like this should do the job:

```
SELECT UserID FROM 
(SELECT RelatingUser AS UserID
 FROM friend
 WHERE RelatedUser = ...
 UNION
 SELECT RelatedUser AS UserID
 FROM friend
 WHERE RelatingUser = ...) AS friends
ORDER BY UserID
```

Comment: for the bottom query, can you tell me what I would echo?

Comment: As the query returns a field named UserID, given your code you will have to echo `$other_friend_assoc['UserID']`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the query to order them?

```
"SELECT * FROM friend WHERE RelatingUser='$users' OR RelatedUser='$users' ORDER BY id ASC"
```

Comment: what would i echo so i could get those results??

Comment: You would check each row's result set and see which key is equivalent to your $users variable.